# Low loss and high val_loss that decreases

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm getting some weird results while training a model. My loss starts very low and gets higher after every epoch, whilst my val_loss starts very high, then gradually gets lower. val_acc is also going up a bit too. I don't get how this could happen. Is this just overfitting?

Here's my model:

```
num_units=96
batch_size=120
sequence_length=10
input_classes=9
output_classes=2
dropout_rate=0.6

model.add(LSTM(num_units, stateful=False, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, sequence_length, input_classes)))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(output_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image: loss]
[image: acc]

Comment: What does your output data look like?

Comment: @djk47463 2 class one-hot output, so like [1, 0] or [0, 1]